# Parse JSON data into HorizontalScrollView with Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, horizontalscrollview

I need to parse JSON data into HorizontalScrollView with Retrofit2. I parsed it into ListView succesfully, but I haven't imagination how to do it into HorizontalScrollView. Google can't give me right answer.

My code with ListView below.

P.S. I want to do HorizontalScrollView instead of ListView.

[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LluXF.png)

**MyForecastAdapter.java**

```
public class MyForecastAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Forecast> {

List<Forecast> forecastList;
Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyForecastAdapter(Context context, List<Forecast> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    forecastList = objects;
}

@Override
public Forecast getItem(int position) {
    return forecastList.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Forecast item = getItem(position);

    viewHolder.textViewTemp.setText(item.getMain().getTemp());
    viewHolder.textViewHumidity.setText(item.getMain().getHumidity());

    return viewHolder.relativeLayout;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public final RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public final TextView textViewTemp;
    public final TextView textViewHumidity;

    private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout relativeLayout, TextView textViewTemp, TextView textViewHumidity) {
        this.relativeLayout = relativeLayout;
        this.textViewTemp = textViewTemp;
        this.textViewHumidity = textViewHumidity;
    }

    public static ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
        TextView textViewTemp = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewTemp);
        TextView textViewHumidity = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewHumidity);
        return new ViewHolder(relativeLayout, textViewTemp, textViewHumidity);
    }
}
```

}

**ForecastList.java**

```
public class ForecastList {

@SerializedName("list")
@Expose
private ArrayList<Forecast> forecasts = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Forecast> getForecasts() {
    return forecasts;
}

public void setForecasts(ArrayList<Forecast> forecasts) {
    this.forecasts = forecasts;
}
```

}

**Forecast.java** - getters/setters.

**ApiService.java**

```
public interface ApiService {

@GET("/data/2.5/forecast?q=Kirov,ru&appid=/../")
Call<ForecastList> getMyJSON();
```

}

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org";

private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static ApiService getApiService() {
    return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    forecastList = new ArrayList<>();
    parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ApiService apiService = RetrofitClient.getApiService();

    Call<ForecastList> call = apiService.getMyJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ForecastList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ForecastList> call, Response<ForecastList> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                forecastList = response.body().getForecasts();

                adapter = new MyForecastAdapter(MainActivity.this, forecastList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ForecastList> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your question, I don't understand what you want to do with horizontalscrollView and list?

Comment: Why is a `ListView` not adequate? A "List" of objects is suited for this exact purpose.  This is not really a programming problem, as your code works.

Comment: I want to do HorizontalScrollView instead of ListView.

Comment: Ok, well just dynamically add views (or create a custom view for your data) to your Horizontal Scroll view and populate them with the data from your list - you can't have a static layout as you don't know the size/count of the arraylist.

Comment: @MarkKeen excuse me, can you add some code for example? I just have not much expirience in coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use horizonatal Scroll View using Recycle View with LinearLayoutManager with constructor** `new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);`

Use this code .....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    forecastList = new ArrayList<>();
    parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ApiService apiService = RetrofitClient.getApiService();

    Call<ForecastList> call = apiService.getMyJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ForecastList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ForecastList> call, Response<ForecastList> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                forecastList = response.body().getForecasts();

                adapter = new MyForecastAdapter(MainActivity.this, forecastList);
                myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ForecastList> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

and change `ListView` into `RecycleView` in XML and in code also.....

Comment: excuse me, but i have an error in "myList.setAdapter(adapter)". "setAdapter in RecyclerView cannot be applied". I did all exactly as you sad. Help pls

Comment: you have to create CustomAdapter extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>`  have look on the example:- http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/